# upload multipart value

Tags: android

I am writing a code in which i am uploading multipart value with file, my code lines are below:

```
    final InputStream gpxInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                        RecordedRouteGPXFormatter.create(recordedGeoPoints).getBytes());
                final HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                final HttpPost request = new HttpPost(UPLOADSCRIPT_URL);

                // create the multipart request and add the parts to it

                final MultipartEntity requestEntity = new MultipartEntity();

                InputStreamBody isb = new InputStreamBody(gpxInputStream, "uploadedFile");

                requestEntity.addPart("uploadedFile",isb);
```

But at the line **"requestEntity.addPart("uploadedFile",isb);"** i am getting ***The type org.apache.james.mime4j.message.AbstractBody cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files*** syntax error. please help me whats wrong with this.

Answer (score 1):

have you add `mime4j.xxx.jar` to your lib folder? You can find it [here](http://archive.apache.org/dist/james/mime4j/)

Comment: Right Bro. Get the solution